# React-create-library Import Image Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating new project using [create-react-library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-library) but when I tried to import image using `import logo from './logo.png'`, the image does not show up in the example, but if I use `import logo from 'logo.png'` the image show up.

My question is this normally happen?

here is the folder structure of my project

[not working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vIse.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBHiJ.png)

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.css'
import logo from './logo.png'

export const ExampleComponent = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.test}>
      {/* Example Component: {text} */}
      <img src={logo} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[working version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKPKE.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8joRI.png)

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.module.css'
import logo from 'logo.png'

export const ExampleComponent = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.test}>
      {/* Example Component: {text} */}
      <img src={logo} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you could show some code, this would help us better understand the hierarchy of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am also new with react-create-library and was having the same problem. My image was in the folder src/assets/img and when I was trying to add the path relatively it was failing.
What i found is path should be after the ./src/ folder.
following is the code that worked for me for the icon in src/assets/img folder.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.module.css';
import warnicon from 'assets/img/warning.png';
.
.
.
<div className={styles.modalBody}>
    <img src={warnicon} alt='warn-icon'></img>
    <p className={styles.warning}>{props.text}</p>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this - sovled it for me.  Using `strace` on the `npm start` command, I discovered that the project looked for the image in the `public/` folder instead of the `dist/` folder when using `"./"` in the import.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is normally the way it happens. Although adding your code would have helped but I have added an example:-

```
 import React from 'react';
 import logo from './logo.png'; 
 console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png
 function Header() {
// Import result is the URL of your image
return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}
```